# insert a variable in middle of code JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a code which is pick the current location and I set 2 cookies to store the latitude and longitude for later use, then I have second code to show this locations on map from the cookies stored.

I have tried to get some info on Google but it did not work.
The way to insert my variables on code is not correct and I could not find a suitable solution to do it

on the line coords:{lat:37.128285,lng:-8.539157},
on the place of the latitude and longitude I want to place my variables
I have try to do something like this but seems my syntax is not correct

```
center:{lat:}+ lati +{,lng:} + longi
```

I have also try like this but get an error

> center:{lat:lati,lng:longi}
>
> InvalidValueError: setCenter: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral with finite coordinates: in property lat: not a number
>
> This is my code to get the current location

```
<html>
    <body>

    <p>Click to get your current coordinates.</p>

    <button id="clickButton" onclick="getLocation()">Get Your Current Location and after refresh this page...</button>

    <p id="demo"></p>

    <script>
    setInterval(function(){ 
    //this code runs every second
    document.getElementById('clickButton').click(); 
    }, 1000);

    var x = document.getElementById("demo");

    function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else { 
    x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
    }

    function showPosition(position) {
    x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
    "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
    document.cookie = "Long = " + position.coords.longitude;
    document.cookie = "Lat = " + position.coords.latitude;
  
    document.cookie = "Longitude = " + position.coords.Longitude;
    }
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

this my code to show the marks on map
In this code I try to set 2 variables with my cookie value and then get implement on my code, but not in correct way
on the line
`coords:{lat:${lati},lng:${longi}},`

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>My Google Map</title>
    <style>
    #map{
      height:400px;
      width:100%;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>My Google Map</h1>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
    var lati = getCookie("lat");
    var longi = getCookie("long");
    function initMap(){
      // Map options
      var options = {
        zoom:8,
        center:{lat:37.128285,lng:-8.539157}
      }
      
      // New map
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), options);

      // Listen for click on map
      google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event){
        // Add marker
        addMarker({coords:event.latLng});
      });

      /*
      // Add marker
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position:{lat:42.4668,lng:-70.9495},
        map:map,
        icon:'C:\Users\MDLABS\Desktop\nice taxy drivers traker\Taxi-icon.png'
      });

      var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content:'<h1>Lynn MA</h1>'
      });

      marker.addListener('click', function(){
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
      });
      */

      // Array of markers
      var markers = [
        {
          coords:{lat:${lati},lng:${longi}},
          iconImage:'https://www.nicetaxi.eu/Taxi-icon.png',
          content:'<h1>driver 1</h1>'
        },
        {
          coords:{lat:37.128285,lng:-8.539157},
          content:'<h1>driver 2</h1>'
        },
        {
          coords:{lat:37.128285,lng:-8.539159}
        }
      ];

      // Loop through markers
      for(var i = 0;i < markers.length;i++){
        // Add marker
        addMarker(markers[i]);
      }

      // Add Marker Function
      function addMarker(props){
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position:props.coords,
          map:map,
          //icon:props.iconImage
        });

        // Check for customicon
        if(props.iconImage){
          // Set icon image
          marker.setIcon(props.iconImage);
        }

        // Check content
        if(props.content){
          var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content:props.content
          });

          marker.addListener('click', function(){
            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
          });
        }
      }
    }
    function getCookie(name) {
    const value = `; ${document.cookie}`;
    const parts = value.split(`; ${name}=`);
    if (parts.length === 2) return parts.pop().split(';').shift();
    }
    </script>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBg8mazOCFsHlsOfTClG9Cugb1ddBPfldU&callback=initMap">
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: _"...but it seems not work."_ -> _"**Describe the problem.** "It doesn't work" isn't descriptive enough to help people understand your problem. Instead, tell other readers what the expected behavior should be. Tell other readers what the exact wording of the error message is, and which line of code is producing it"_

Comment: What does the question title have to do with what's posted in the question itself?

Comment: You are setting the cookies with capitalized names (`Lat`, `Lon`) but are accessing with lowercase names (`lat`, `lon`). Also the way you are extracting the values doesn't seem right.

Comment: @Andreas: `document.cookie` is special. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/api/document/cookie#write_a_new_cookie

Comment: @Pointy in the second code in the line coords:{lat:${lati},lng:${longi}} that is the question title about but this code is not correct

Comment: `coords:{lat:${lati},lng:${longi}},` is a syntax error.

Comment: @Andreas Yes that was my try to insert my variables in place of the numbers but thats not correct there is an syntaxe error

Comment: Using variables in an object literal is not different from using literals: `var obj = {lat: 37.128285}` is the same as `const someVar = 37.128285; const obj = {lat: someVar}`. There is no special syntax. And you seem to know this already because you do that in other places already: `{map:map}`, `{content: props.content}` , etc

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution to make it work. This is the final working code that solves it:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>My Google Map</title>
        <style>
            #map {
                height: 400px;
                width: 100%;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>My Google Map</h1>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
        var lati = parseFloat(getCookie("Lat"));
        var longi = parseFloat(getCookie("Long"));
    
        function initMap() {
            // Map options
            var options =
                {
                    zoom: 8,
                    center: {lat: lati, lng: longi}
                }
    
            // New map
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), options);
    
            // Listen for click on map
            google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (event) {
                // Add marker
                addMarker({coords: event.latLng});
            });
    
            /*
            // Add marker
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position:{lat:42.4668,lng:-70.9495},
              map:map,
              icon:'C:\Users\MDLABS\Desktop\nice taxy drivers traker\Taxi-icon.png'
            });
    
            var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
              content:'<h1>Lynn MA</h1>'
            });
    
            marker.addListener('click', function(){
              infoWindow.open(map, marker);
            });
            */
    
            // Array of markers
            var markers = [
                {
                    coords: {lat: 37.128285, lng: -8.539157},
                    iconImage: 'https://www.nicetaxi.eu/Taxi-icon.png',
                    content: '<h1>driver 1</h1>'
                }
            ];
    
            // Loop through markers
            for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                // Add marker
                addMarker(markers[i]);
            }
    
            // Add Marker Function
            function addMarker(props) {
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: props.coords,
                    map: map,
                    //icon:props.iconImage
                });
    
                // Check for customicon
                if (props.iconImage) {
                    // Set icon image
                    marker.setIcon(props.iconImage);
                }
    
                // Check content
                if (props.content) {
                    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                        content: props.content
                    });
    
                    marker.addListener('click', function () {
                        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    
        function getCookie(name) {
            const value = `; ${document.cookie}`;
            const parts = value.split(`; ${name}=`);
            if (parts.length === 2) return parts.pop().split(';').shift();
        }
    </script>
    <script async defer
            src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&callback=initMap">
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```